# What are the set numbers for these Star Wars and Police sets?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I recently bought some old sets and stumbled across these 2 set-remains. One is obviously a Star Wars set, maybe someone knows the number? I wonder if the other one, the future police, is a MOC instead of an official set?  [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The police vehicle is from  [7035-1: Police HQ](https://brickset.com/sets/7035-1/Police-HQ)

- based on [Wedge 6 x 2 Left with Police World City Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=41748pb010&in=S)

The last picture is from 
[7748-1: Corporate Alliance Tank Droid](https://brickset.com/sets/7748-1/Corporate-Alliance-Tank-Droid)

- based on [Light Bluish Gray Dish 10 x 10 Inverted (Radar) with SW Tank Droid Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50990pb04&colorID=86&in=A)

Comment: thanx Syberion. never heard of World City. just when you think you know it all... ;-)